# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::vehicles()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have two models.
A "**Vehicle**" and a "**Tenant**".

They have following relationships with each other.

> A Tenant hasMany vehicles. A vehicle belongsTo a single Tenant.

**For Tenant.php:**

```
public function vehicles()
{
    return $this->hasMany('\App\Models\Vehicle');
}
```

**For Vehicle.php:**

```
public function tenant()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('\App\Models\Tenant');
}
```

Executing this :

```
 $this->user = $request->user();
    $userTenant = $this->user->tenant();
    $vehicle= $userTenant->vehicles()->first();
```

results in an error

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::vehicles()
```

Pointing to this line :

```
$vehicle= $userTenant->vehicles()->first();
```

I am not so sure why is this happening =\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see from your post what the relations are with a `User`, but the `tenant()` (with parentheses) probably returns a `BelongsTo` or other `Relation` instance that is being assigned to `$userTenant`. Try changing that line to a version without parentheses after `tenant` to get the Tenant Model instance instead:

```
$userTenant = $this->user->tenant;
```

**Update from comments**

when you call a relation as method, e.g.

`$myModel->relation()`

you get the corresponding relation class. When used as a getter, e.g.

`$myModel->relation`

it's essentially the same thing as calling

`$myModel->relation()->get()` for relations that target multiple models, or calling

`$myModel->relation()->first()` for relations that target a single model.

Checkout the docs for more info on [relationship methods vs. dynamic properties](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#relationship-methods-vs-dynamic-properties)

Comment: What do you mean by returning "BelongsTo" or other "Relation" instance ?

Comment: when you call a relation as method, e.g. `...->relation()` you get the corresponding relation class. When used as a getter, e.g. `...->relation` it's essentially the same thing as calling `...->relation()->get()` for relations that target multiple models, or calling `...->relation()->first()` for relations that target a single model.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, which part of docs should I revise for "this" particular topic ? Eloquent relationships ?

Comment: This should be it: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#relationship-methods-vs-dynamic-properties